# Check which mouse button was pressed and if its a double click?

Tags: javascript

I have a canvas which listens for mouse down event... but I wanted to make it more detailed by listening on the buttons and if they were double clicks or not.

I have this:

```
 canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", what_button, false);
```

Then a function named what_button:

```
 function what_button(e){
 //check which button on the mouse
 //was it a double click ?

 }
```

Is this possible in JavaScript?

Comment: There is a `'dblclick'` event on which you can bind a handler to...

Comment: True but then that would call both mouse down + the dbl click ?

Comment: Your application expects double-clicks with the right mouse button? I can't think of any program where a right button double-click has a function...

Comment: It doesn't yet but i would like the options available to me >.>

Comment: sorry did not paste the link here it is http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the `'mousedown'` event is able to anticipate whether or not a second mouse click will occur. You'll have to bind to both `'click'` and `'dblclick'` and then override the behavior if a double-click occurred...

Inside the handler, the `e.button` property tells you which button was clicked:

```
0 => left
1 => middle
2 => right
```

---

This works for me:

```
var dblclick;
var timeout;

$( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
    if ( !timeout ) {
        timeout = setTimeout( function () {
            timeout = 0;           
            handler( dblclick ? 'dblclick' : 'click' );
            dblclick = false;
        }, 200 );
    }
});

$( document ).on( 'dblclick', function ( e ) {
    dblclick = true;
});

// this function receives either 'click' or 'dblclick'
// and performs the corresponding action
function handler ( type ) {
    alert( type );
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/f73tY/1/

I use a delay value of `200`. I have found that (at least on my machine) a value of `100` does not detect a double-click.

Comment: Is there a way to do if dblclick == false then its a click type check on event listener?

Comment: @Dave The thing is when you double-click, the first `'click'` handler is executed immediately after you clicked for the first time and *before* you clicked the second time. So, the handler obviously cannot know if this is the first click of a double-click. (The second click did not yet occur by the time the first click handler is executed.)

Comment: So what if i use a timer in the function it calls and calculate the difference between the two times then if its lower than a certain value it would count as a double click ?

Comment: @Dave I have updated my answer with a solution. (I use jQuery to bind the events, but that is irrelevant for the functionality of my code.)

Comment: Regarding the mouse button numbers, that might be what they are **supposed** to be, but browsers disagree, see [Javascript Madness: Mouse Events](http://www.unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html). The whole concept of "left", "right" and "middle" is wrong–headed, it assigns significance to the buttons' spatial relationship whereas it should be based on some other criterion (e.g. purpose). Note in the [Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent) it says to reverse them for mice "configured for left handed use". So what meaning does "left" and "right" have now?

Comment: @RobG I tested in FF, Chrome, Opera, and IE9, and those numbers work in those browsers. IE7/8 report different values, but the OP mentioned it's for a CANVAS, so I didn't find it necessary to provide a solution for those browsers as well. *** Well, yea, "left" and "right" are not good terms. The question is, what percentage of users have configured their mice for left handed use. Is that percentage significant?

Comment: There are (and always have been) a great variety of pointing devices. The terms "left", "right" and "middle" for device buttons were never appropriate and should have been something like "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", and so on. I wish the writers of W3C specifications would fix that. The idea that someone using a left handed mouse would necessarily reverse the buttons is also not necessarily true. Some left-handed guitarists use standard string order, others reverse them. Ever seen a left handed piano? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `click`/`dblclick`:

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');

button.ondblclick = function() {
    doubleClick = true;
};​
```

You can even add an `normalClick = false` then use that information in your code.

Comment: You're example is not using an event listener =/ ? How would that work on a canvas?

Comment: Do you mean event listener like this: `button.addEventListener('dblclick'...)`?? Because it can work the same way.

Comment: Yes but that would only allow dblclick not the option for either/or.