# Prevent double click of some element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a clickable `<td>` which does some action. However, strange things happen when I quickly make double click. Thus, I want to prevent it and make sure it is only single clickable event.

```
$.each(response, function(index) {
    $('#myID').append('<tr><td onclick="select(this)" >'+ response[index] +'</td></tr>');
});

function select(element){
...
}
```

I tried to use jQuery's `.one()` function, but this code above is a product of another event. So, I cannot use `$(document).ready();` here. In my knowledge I have to make it like `onclick="select(this)"`... And it works. But here I need to disable double clicking.

Any help?

Comment: can't the select function just handle the case?

Comment: Handling the case has to be in select function. But how?

Comment: You can consider this as a tip to achieve it. You can add a class while creating the 'td' element. Then you can write the code like: 
$(".newClassAdded").on("dblclick", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });

Comment: @VinayGayakwad that won’t work, the `click` event will still fire two times. This needs to be done using a flag, set by the dblclick handler, and then evaluated inside the click handler. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9969252/10283047

Comment: @harunB10 so what is select doing? What is causing the issue when it is clicked twice. I need that basic info so I know why it is an issue with clicking twice.

Comment: @epascarello `select` is making an `$.ajax( )` request.

Comment: I assume you are achieving this in the way you have outlined for a very valid reason as there are other ways of better handling this scenario. I suspect you will need to either introduce a timestamp and check against it for dbl click or some sort of delay in the select function to achieve your goal. Something that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately

Comment: You can have a look at the answer in the link shared by @misorude . I believe that approach could help you to make it work .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So add a check that the Ajax request is active....

```
function select(element){
  var elem = $(element);
  if(elem.hasClass("active")) {  // is ajax call active?
    return false;
  }
  elem.addClass("active");  // set it that it is active
  $.ajax({
    url: "foo"
  })
    .done(function(){})
    .always(function(){
      elem.removeClass("active");  // call is done, so remove active state
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable button until ajax finishes its operation

```
function select(element){
    $(element).prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        url'url',
        success:function(response){
            $(element).prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
}
```